# Hexagon does not show

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a problem with my code, im trying to draw a hexagon polygon, but nth show up.  When i'm trying with eclipse or other pygame.draw functions its ok, problem is with polygons. Here is my code. I think whole program is working fine, the problem is here :

```
hexagon = Hexagon.hexagon_generator(40,self.rect.x,self.rect.y)
pygame.draw.polygon(self.image,(0,225,0),list(hexagon),0)
```

Whole program:

```
import pygame
import random
import Hexagon

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([100,100])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        hexagon = Hexagon.hexagon_generator(40,self.rect.x,self.rect.y)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image,(0,225,0),list(hexagon),0)

        self.velocity_y = 0
        self.velocity_x = 0

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.velocity_x += x
        self.velocity_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity_x
        self.rect.y += self.velocity_y
        if self.rect.x >785:
            self.rect.x =785
        elif self.rect.x <0:
            self.rect.x =0
        elif self.rect.y > 585:
            self.rect.y = 585
        elif self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        elif self.rect.x<0 and self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
            self.rect.y = 0

pygame.init()
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player(200,200)
all_sprites_list.add(player)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.move(0,5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.move(0, -5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move(-5, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move(5, 0)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.move(0, -5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.move(0, 5)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move(5, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move(-5, 0)

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites_list.update()

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

There is a Hexagon module:

```
import math

def hexagon_generator(edge_length, x,y):
    for angle in range(0, 360, 60):
        x += math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * edge_length
        y += math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * edge_length
        yield x, y
```

Comment: I've just fixed the formatting, but you should still try to reduce the code to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The two modules could also be joined.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the values that `hexagon_generator` yields, you'll see that the points are outside of the image (which has a size of 100*100 pixels).

```
[(240.0, 200.0), (260.0, 234.64101615137753), (240.0, 269.28203230275506), (200.0, 269.28203230275506), (179.99999999999997, 234.64101615137753), (199.99999999999997, 200.0)]
```

You shouldn't use the world coordinates of the player as the start `x, y` values. If the hexagon should be centered, you can just pass the half edge length of the image to the generator and add it to `x` and `y`:

```
def hexagon_generator(edge_length):
    for angle in range(0, 360, 60):
        x = math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * edge_length + edge_length
        y = math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * edge_length + edge_length
        yield x, y
```